# Get SQL Server 2008 Management Studio icons

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I want to get icons from SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. Is it free ? If so where can I download it ?

Comment: I doubt that a public forum for developers would be the best place to ask for pirate copies of anything. If you want to get any helpful responses I'd suggest removing the last bit of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [many free for commercial use icons](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=table) that are almost identical to those in SSMS.

Comment: I knew about that site. I found some icons there. I hoped to find free microsoft icons which looks exactly the ms ones.

However, your answer is useful so I marked it as a green sign.

Answer (score 3):

I found answer on my question here:

http://sql-server-performance.com/Community/forums/p/1567/8688.aspx

It's not legal to use these icons without permission from Microsoft. bee